# Apache Ignite Backup cache Node identification

Tags: caching, backup, ignite

I have started using Apache Ignite for my current project. I have set up the ignite Cluster with 3 Server Nodes with Backup Cache count as 1. Ignite Client Node is able to create a primary Cache as well as Backup cache in the cluster. But here I want to know for a particular cache which is Primary node and on which Node the Backup Cache is stored. Is there any tool available or any Visor command to do so along with finding the size of each cache.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Visor CLI shows how many primary and backup partitions each node holds.

By default, a cache is split into 1024 partitions. You can change that by configuring affinity function.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [control.sh](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/control-script) and inspect some specific partition distribution.

```
 --cache distribution nodeId|null [cacheName1,...,cacheNameN] [--user-attributes attrName1,...,attrNameN]

    Prints the information about partition distribution.
```

This commands prints partition distribution across nodes.

Sample:

```
 ./control.sh --cache distribution null myCache

[groupId,partition,nodeId,primary,state,updateCounter,partitionSize,nodeAddresses]
[next group: id=1482644790, name=myCache]
1482644790,0,e27ad549,P,OWNING,0,0,[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.0.75.1, 127.0.0.1, 172.23.45.97, 172.25.4.211]
```